# Inserted EmailMessage always "Outbound"?

Tags: emailmessage

We have an inbound Email handler that currently just creates a Task. I'd like to update it to create an EmailMessage object instead. However I've noticed that when viewing the Apex-inserted object in Salesforce it appears with a heading of "Outbound Email Message".

Is there a way to signal to Salesforce, when creating an EmailMessage, that it was in fact inbound?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the Incomng field to true. See [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm):

> **Field**
>   Incoming
>
> **Type**
>   boolean
>
> **Properties**
>   Create, Defaulted on create, Filter
>
> **Description**
>   Indicates whether the email was received (true) or sent (false).

Comment: Thank you! I would not have noticed that easily. On a related note, it always produces an Email with status "Draft", and the related Activity it generates is always "In Progress". Is there a way to have the Email end up with a different status than Draft and/or have it generate a "Completed" Activity without doing a second DML update after?

Comment: @CharlesT You should be able to set the Status field, too.

Comment: Ahh OK I did not realize I had to use numbers in the picklist. http://blog.crmscience.com/2013/02/emailmessage-status-values.html